# Displaying values t-wise (x-Axis) arriving from serial port in MS-Chart, C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timer, serial-port, mschart

I am getting via the serial port some values from an aquisition board. I want to display the values on Y-axis and also have the time on the x-Axis. The values come from the serial port in batches that are NOT of equal size. I therefore created a time-stamp of my own. It doesn't work as seen in the picture below. However, if I set it to x-coordinate to 0 in AddXY, i get my result but of course without the time on the x-axis. I want to have it in seconds. I use a timer set to get data every 500 ms.

```
 private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string data;

            data = _port.ReadExisting();

            Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
            ax.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;
            ax.Interval = 500;
            chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
            ax.LabelStyle.Format = "ss";

            var dataBlocks = data.Split('\n');
            int counter = 0;
            double delta = (double)dataBlocks.Length / (double)500;
            foreach (var block in dataBlocks)
            {
                var numbers = block.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
                {
                    double n = double.NaN;
                    bool ok = double.TryParse(numbers[i], out n);
                    if (ok)
                    {
                        if (n > 100)
                        {
                            double temp = counter * delta;
                           // double temp = 0;
                            chart1.Series[i].Points.AddXY(temp, n);
                            counter++;
                            if (chart1.Series[0].Points.Count > 1000)
                                chart1.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                            //chart1.ResetAutoValues();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

 timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Interval = 500;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1024;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart1.Series[0].Name = "Semnal EKG";[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: At the moment you are doing all at once (reading the data processing it and displaying it on the chart, perhaps keeping them separate will help you display the correct thing on chart. Although you are retrieving the data every 500ms, there are no timestamp against the data, so you could easily keep them in a dictionary and display them as block of data arrived for every tick.

Comment: I think you need to pass your x value in as a DateTime format.  You are just passing it a double which is why your x-axis is trying to format as a double.